# EF6 - code-first - how to properly handle deleting a parent entry from an m:n relationship

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6, parent-child, foreign-key-relationship

I have a situation where I have two entities - `ItemGroup` and `Item` - that are linked in a m:n fashion:

```
CREATE TABLE ItemGroup
(
    ItemGroupId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    ItemGroupName VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE Item
(
    ItemId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    ItemName VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE ItemGroup_Item
(
    ItemGroupId INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_ItemGroupItem_ItemGroup
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.ItemGroup(ItemGroupId),
    ItemId INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_ItemGroupItem_Item
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Item(ItemId),

    CONSTRAINT PK_Itemgroup_Item
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(ItemGroupId, ItemId)
)
```

Therefore, in my SQL Server database, I have a "link" table that connects the two entities by including their respective primary keys.

When I re-engineer this into an EF 6 model, I get these two classes:

```
[Table("Item")]
public partial class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
        ItemGroup = new HashSet<ItemGroup>();
    }

    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ItemGroup> ItemGroup { get; set; }
}

[Table("ItemGroup")]
public partial class ItemGroup
{
    public ItemGroup()
    {
        Item = new HashSet<Item>();
    }

    public int ItemGroupId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ItemGroupName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> Item { get; set; }
}
```

and the `DbContext` class contains this fluent setup:

```
public partial class ItemGroupModel : DbContext
{
    public ItemGroupModel() : base("name=ItemGroupConn")
    { }

    public virtual DbSet<Item> Item { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ItemGroup> ItemGroup { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
            .Property(e => e.ItemName)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
            .HasMany(e => e.ItemGroup)
            .WithMany(e => e.Item)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("ItemGroup_Item").MapLeftKey("ItemId").MapRightKey("ItemGroupId"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<ItemGroup>()
            .Property(e => e.ItemGroupName)
            .IsUnicode(false);
    }
}
```

My troubles start when I'm trying to delete an `ItemGroup`:

```
using(ItemGroupModel ctx = new ItemGroupModel())
{
    ItemGroup grp = ctx.ItemGroup.FirstOrDefault();

    ctx.ItemGroup.Remove(grp);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

What I want to have EF do in this case would be to delete all entries from that "link" table (which isn't modelled as a separate entity in EF), and then delete the entry in `ItemGroup` itself. The entries in `Item` **MUST NOT** be touched!

Trouble is : since this link table isn't an actual entity in my EF model, how can I ensure those link entries will be in fact deleted, but not the `Item` that they link to? So I cannot really handle deleting the "child" entries manually - there are no child entries I can access....

How can I handle this nicely? Sometimes it seems to work - other times I get an exception saying that the `DELETE` statement conflicted with the entries that are still present in `ItemGroup_Item` ....

Comment: what about cascade delete ?

Comment: @isxaker: I saw that being used in some cases, but those were all 1:n relationships between two separate entities - not m:n with a "hidden" link table. I cannot seem to define cascade delete in this setup here in the fluent EF API ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone stumbles across this problem, too - here's the solution: I needed to call the `.Clear()` method on the navigation property of the `ItemGroup` object before saving. That "disconnects" any `Item`'s this `ItemGroup` was linked to, without actually removing the underlying `Item` objects themselves - just the entries in the junction table are gone:

```
using(ItemGroupModel ctx = new ItemGroupModel())
{
    ItemGroup grp = ctx.ItemGroup.FirstOrDefault();

    // call Item.Clear() to remove any entries in the navigation
    // property which translates into any entries in the junction table
    // in the underlying database
    grp.Item.Clear();

    ctx.ItemGroup.Remove(grp);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: EF will assume (by convention) that the foreign keys in the database have cascaded delete. If EF would generate a database from your class model, you'd see `ON DELETE CASCADE` in the constraints. So you'll be OK if you add them to your data model. Your solution does work, but `grp.Item.Clear();` first (lazily) loads all `Item` entities of the group from the database. That's a lot of overhead.

Comment: @GertArnold: OK - I'm not letting EF generate my database (just yet), so I haven't gotten into that problem - but **how else** would you solve this problem? How would you **properly and efficiently** remove the `Item` entries from the junction table, **without** actually deleting the linked `Item` rows ?